# How to load and draw texture correctly in OpenGLES with Mono for Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, xamarin.android

I recently was porting my own 2D rendering engine to Android by using Mono for Android
Everything went well except I cannot draw the texture at all, all textures are looking like empty.

So I started a new clean project to test it, and I wrote it according to the sample code for java, what I found out is that I cannot draw the texture either.
Here is the code I used for testing:

```
class GLView1 : AndroidGameView
{
    public GLView1(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
        this.GLContextVersion = OpenTK.Graphics.GLContextVersion.Gles1_1;
    }

    // This gets called when the drawing surface is ready
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        // Run the render loop
        Run();
    }

    bool initialized = false;
    int[] textureID = new int[1];
    // This gets called on each frame render
    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);
        if (!initialized)
        {
            initialized = true;
            GL.Enable(All.Texture2D);
            GL.GenTextures(1, textureID);
            GL.ShadeModel(All.Smooth);
            GL.BindTexture(All.Texture2D, textureID[0]);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.Icon);
            Android.Opengl.GLUtils.TexImage2D(Android.Opengl.GLES10.GlTexture2d, 0, Android.Opengl.GLES10.GlRgba, bitmap, 0);
            bitmap.Recycle();

            GL.TexParameter(All.Texture2D, All.TextureMinFilter, (int)All.Nearest);
            GL.TexParameter(All.Texture2D, All.TextureMagFilter, (int)All.Linear);
        }
        GL.ClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
        GL.Clear((uint)All.ColorBufferBit);

        GL.BindTexture(All.Texture2D, textureID[0]);

        GL.EnableClientState(All.VertexArray);
        GL.EnableClientState(All.TextureCoordArray);
        GL.FrontFace(All.Cw);

        GL.VertexPointer(2, All.Float, 0, square_vertices);
        GL.TexCoordPointer(2, All.Float, 0, uv);

        GL.DrawArrays(All.TriangleStrip, 0, 4);

        SwapBuffers();
    }

    float[] uv ={
                    0,1,
                    0,0,
                    1,1,
                    1,0,
               };

    float[] square_vertices = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f,
        0.5f, -0.5f,
        -0.5f, 0.5f, 
        0.5f, 0.5f,
    };

    byte[] square_colors = {
        255, 255,   0, 255,
        0,   255, 255, 255,
        0,     0,    0,  0,
        255,   0,  255, 255,
    };
}
```

What I saw on my Android device is just a big white square.

PS: I tested it again with Android Emulator, and it seems this code works in android emulator, but on my real device it is still showing a big white square.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a shader? It looks like you're requesting a gles2.0 context, which I believe doesn't support any fixed pipeline.

Comment: well, shader is working fine, compiled well, vertex shader transformed the coordinates to screen space correctly, and I can control the output color via fragment shader, just the color=texture2D(SAMPLER0, TexCoord.st) is equal(0,0,0,0).  for the sample code above, it's the same if I use GLES1_1 context

Comment: I think you need to start hunting for gl errors with glGetError (or mono equivalent). What you have there really doesn't look like gles2.0 code. glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) is illegal on opengles2.0, and glEnableClientState/glVertexPointer are not a real functions either in 2.0. You need to use the shader equivalent, which is glEnableVertexAttribArray/glVertexAttribPointer.

Comment: I just edited my code above, the line :"OpenTK.Graphics.GLContextVersion.Gles2_0" was added just for testing, I was using 1_1 context which has the same result, big white square. I tested with glGetError, I added it after every GL operation in the initialization part, and all returened NoError

Comment: I just found out something interesting, this code worked in Android Emulator, but didn't on real device. In emulator it showed the icon correctly, but on real device a white square. Any clue about this?

Comment: If you are using a shader (you said "shader is compiling fine"), can you post the source?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with BitmapFactory.decodeResource(). I was getting the same issue, but when I use openRawResource() to open the resource as a stream and then use BitmapFactory.decodeStream() to load the bitmap then the textures suddenly appear.

Looking further at BitmapFactory.decodeResource(), it seems to scale based on the target device's pixel density. See this: http://blog.poweredbytoast.com/loading-opengl-textures-in-android

This would cause all your neat power-of-2-sized textures to be funny sized that the hardware acceleration doesn't recognise (the emulator doesn't care about non-power-of-2 sizes). So, use the code from the link above, copied here for your convenience:

```
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
opts.inScaled = false;
```